Docx file converted from PDF file cannot be opened by online version of Microsoft 365
I used pdf2docx library to converte a 2 page document to word. The document has few graphics, a company logo and text boxes. The final docx document is readable by note pad(minor loss of formatting), Microsoft 365 desktop version(no loss of formatting) but cannot be opened by online version of Microsoft office 365. The error message I get is that "word ran into a problem" after opening few lines.
Is this a formatting question or a Microsoft 365 issue. What can I do to make solve it since I want to share with people who have no desktop version of microsoft office?
Here is the script I used
import os
from pdf2docx import parse
pdf_file_path = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\file_name.pdf'
pdf_file = pdf_file_path
word_file = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\file_name.docx'
parse(pdf_file, word_file, start=0, end=None)

